# Multiple XML Namespaces in tag with LXML

Tags: python, xml, lxml, gpx

I am trying to use Pythons LXML library to create a GPX file that can be read by Garmin's Mapsource Product. The header on their GPX files looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" 
     creator="MapSource 6.15.5" version="1.1" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd">
```

When I use the following code:

```
xmlns = "http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"
xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
schemaLocation = "http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd"
version = "1.1"
ns = "{xsi}"

getXML = etree.Element("{" + xmlns + "}gpx", version=version, attrib={"{xsi}schemaLocation": schemaLocation}, creator='My Product', nsmap={'xsi': xsi, None: xmlns})
print(etree.tostring(getXML, xml_declaration=True, standalone='Yes', encoding="UTF-8", pretty_print=True))
```

I get:

```
<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\' standalone=\'yes\'?>
<gpx xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:ns0="xsi"
     ns0:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd"
     version="1.1" creator="My Product"/>
```

Which has the annoying `ns0` tag. This might be perfectly valid XML but Mapsource does not appreciate it.

Any idea how to get this to not have the `ns0` tag?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is with your attribute name.

```
attrib={"{xsi}schemaLocation" : schemaLocation},
```

puts schemaLocation in the xsi namespace.

I think you meant

```
attrib={"{" + xsi + "}schemaLocation" : schemaLocation}
```

to use the URL for xsi. This matches your uses of namespace variables in the element name. It puts the attribute in the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` namespace

That gives the result of

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<gpx xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
     xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd" 
     version="1.1" 
     creator="My Product"/>
```

Comment: See this is why I am an amateur and don't code for a living! 

Perfect answer. 

Thanks!